# Edit config file on demand instance ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2

Each ec2 instance that launched in amazon has the same software but I need to change the file /home/project/config.json for each. What is the easiest way to do this?

I need it done automatically.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom AMIs to launch an instance that is configured any way you like.

- Launch one of the standard AMIs to serve as a base.
- Make whatever changes you want to that instance (in this case, add the file).
- Right click on the running server in the AWS Console.
- Choose '`Create Image (EBS AMI)`'
- If you don't want the instance to be stopped then check '`No Reboot`'. It's better to leave it unchecked if you can and allow it to reboot. This ensures file system integrity is maintained.

In a few minutes a new AMI will be created that you can launch instances with all the changes you made baked in.